# Android studio mouse sometime not working?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am using

- Android studio 2.1.1 Build #AI-143.2821654 build on April 28, 2016.
- JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86_64
- OS X El Capitan  10.11.3

I have met Android studio mouse problem a lot of times recently. I cannot use mouse to click anything in Android studio. All I can do is to use keyboard and shortcuts.

And only solution I found is to restart my whole computer. I have noticed that there is [problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188228) in other version of Android studio. So my question is that how can I deal with it?

I found that sometime I can reproduce this problem after I middle click the Editor Tab to close tab.

[image: Android studio not working]

Comment: Can't reproduce this. You'd better re-install the software

Comment: later I found that may be related to some compatible problem with mouse and touch pad enhance tool https://www.boastr.net/ .

Comment: I got some similar issues with studio. Sometimes I stop getting cursor at editor. Then I need to restart my studio. It happened because the time on my windows keep changing inbetween. Like sometimes it goes 1 month ahead, sometimes 2022.

Comment: I'm currently running into the same thing. I haven't found a fix yet...

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

Just had this issue this morning. Android Studio wasn't responding to mouse click events. The odd thing was that it was responding to mouse position (tooltips, hover effects).

I updated to the newest version of Android Studio using `Android Studio > Check for Updates` and navigated the dialog menu with tab and spacebar. This did not solve the issue, but is probably worthwhile to try.

I'm not 100% certain what solved it, but I started pressing other buttons on my mouse (right-click, middle click, etc). Eventually it started accepting my left-click input again.

Comment: Same issue happened with me, add clicking the back and forward button on my mouse, and then clicking the left button solved the issue (my mouse has 5 buttons, left click, middle click, center click and two buttons on the side for forward and back)

Comment: This is the weirdest bug AND fix I have seen in a while. No idea what caused it an even less idea why the fix worked. But simultaneously clicking my back and forward buttons on my mouse resolved it. Thanks @kbsbng

Comment: I just had the same problem and a simple right click fixed it for me.

Comment: Same issue with me. I fix it by clicking the right, left and middle click simultaneously. The issue happens to me on flutter built websites, some whatsapp web components and of course in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Android Studio (4.1.1) on my MacBook Pro (macOS 11.1). For me, I just restarted my MacBook and the mouse click started working on Android Studio.
Not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me with Intellij IDEA, when a dialog window has been opened by the IDE, but for some reason it is hidden behind the main window. You may try to find if there is any open dialog and close it.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse clicks thing and closing the android studio from task manager and open again did not help for me. im not sure why but CTRL+ALT+DELETE and going back to desktop fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed this issue:

1. Use keyboard arrows and tab key to navigate to google assistant
2. Press enter to launch it
3. type and search "Power Menu : Software Power Bu"
4. navigate to install the app in results from playstore
5. Open the app after install and accept & set permissions
6. Open Power Menu now And you will get Android Power Options
7. Navigate to "Restart" and restart device

Viola!!! Now Emulator clicks works

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened, because one of the plugins started crashing in the loop, somehow disabling mouse click handlers.

#### Verify logs

Log file location:
`~/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/`

#### Remove bad plugins

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/plugins`